# Terminal Error: .zshrc:export:8: not valid in this context: -v

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I am getting this error whenever I start up Terminal on my Mac:

```
.zshrc:export:8: not valid in this context: -v
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Last semester I tried to download HomeBrew on my Mac for a class but ran into some problems, resulting in the error.

Comment: Please post the output of the command `awk ‘NR >= 6 && NR <= 10’ .zshrc` with an edit to the original question. Reply to this comment with an @Allan so I am notified.

Comment: And the contents you added to line 8 are...?